# Is there a way to use pipe to transfer only one parameter to the script?

Tags: shell, pipe, parameter-passing

This command can split a large_file to several files:

```
split -l 200 large_file prefix
```

Each file have 200 lines and named after prefix.

How to use pipe to transfer the parameters to split?

```
cat large_file | split -l 200 prefix  # this command doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat large_file | split -l 200 - prefix # - means stdin
```

This is pretty conventional in many Unix programs: `-` means stdin (or stdout if it were an output file).  So much so that some programs don't even document the behavior, though [`man split`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) does:

> With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

Comment: Many Thanks! Didn't notice it before. It is just under the description part of the man split...